# Reading from file which contain dots

Tags: haskell

I have file txt which contain two numbers, for example:

2.

3.

How can you see, each end of line is ended with dot.

How can I read it and print for example sum of this numbers?

If my file don't contain dots, so for example I have

2

3

it isn't problem. My code is:

```
main3 = do
    x <- openFile "C:/Users/file.txt"  ReadMode
    m <- hGetLine x
    n <- hGetLine x
    return ((read m::Int)+(read n::Int))
```

and it work good. But when in my file are dots, i don't know what can I do. Maybe are any library?

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trouble is that `read` won't parse `"3."` to mean `3`. If you just want to do this in a hacky way, you can drop the last character.

```
main4 = do
    x <- openFile "C:/Users/file.txt"  ReadMode
    m <- hGetLine x
    n <- hGetLine x
    return ((read (init m)::Int)+(read (init n)::Int))
```

which may work but is quite fragile since it assumes that the only non-digit character in each line is the last. We can do a little better by assuming the first `n` digit characters form our numbers

```
import Data.Char

-- takeWhile isDigit :: String -> String

main5 path = do
  f <- readFile path
  numberStrings <- map (takeWhile isDigit) (lines f)
  sum (map read numberStrings)
```

The most robust solution would be to upgrade to a "parser combinator library" like Parsec which would let you write out the grammar of your text file.

Comment: See my answer for a example using parsec

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to do it.. The simplest being

```
main = do
  text <- readFile "file.txt" -- Grab the file
  let nums = map read . map init . lines $ text
  print $ sum nums
```

`init` just drops the `.`. However I'd write it like this

```
import Text.Parsec.String
import Text.Parsec
import Control.Applicative ((<*), (<$>))

getNums :: Parser [Int]
getNums = num `sepEndBy` newline
    where num = read <$> many1 digit <* char '.'

main = parseFromFile getNums "filename" >>= print . fmap sum
```

Is it worth using parsec for something like this?  The answer is "it depends". My rule of thumb is that if I'm planning to use it more than once, then just bite the bullet and use parsec. It's much, much easier to modify something that uses a library like parsec for new and more complex formats. Plus you get free [decent] error messages this way.

Comment: If you bite the bullet and use uu-parsinglib you get GREAT error messages!

Comment: @tel Well they're certainly better than `Error prelude *** No parse` or  whatever :)

Answer (score 0):

You can to this in several steps, exploiting Haskell's monadic API:

1. Read in the file line per line
2. Check whether each line is ended with a dot: Use map and return a Maybe monad: Nothing when the line is not ended with a dot, Just (value without dot) when the line ended with a dot
3. Use map + flatten to convert each String to a number, again with the Maybe monad. Nothing when there is an error, or Just x to contain the number
4. Sum the values using fold

When I have some time, I will try to build an example. It's always fun to play with Haskell's monadic API.